# Red x marks along lines after adding a length field?

Tags: qgis-2

I added a "length" field to a shapefile of lines called "roads".

QGIS puts red x's along the length of the road afterward.

Why is this, and can I make these go away?

Answer (score 6):

You are probably in edit mode. Right Click Layer > Toggle Editing.

Comment: No need to restart QGIS.